# Multilingual routes - Advanced constraints not taken into consideration when paths are generated by url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a multilingual site in rails 3.2 that has some language-specific routes that map to the same action. Like:

For mydomain.fr

```
match "/bonjour_monde" => 'foo#bar'
```

For mydomain.de

```
match "/hallo_welt" => 'foo#bar'
```

To solve this I have used an advanced constraint when declaring the routes:

```
Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(SiteInitializer.for_country("fr")) do
    match "/bonjour_monde" => 'foo#bar'
  end
  constraints(SiteInitializer.for_country("de")) do
    match "/hallo_welt" => 'foo#bar'
  end
end
```

Where the SiteInitializer is just a class which responds to the matches? method and determines if the request is for the correct domain. This is actually only pseudo-code just demonstrating my setup.

```
class SiteInitializer
  def initialize(country_code)
    @country_code = country_code
  end

  def self.for_country(country_code)
    new(country_code)
  end

  def matches?(request)
    # based on the request, decide if this route should be declared
    decide_which_country_code_from_request(request) == @country_code
  end
end
```

This works fine. When requesting mysite.fr/bonjour_monde the app dispatches correctly and the paths are only bound to their specific domain.

```
mysite.fr/bonjour_monde => HTTP 200
mysite.fr/hallo_welt => HTTP 404
mysite.de/bonjour_monde => HTTP 404
mysite.de/hallo_welt => HTTP 200
```

Now, all is fine unless you start using things like url_for(:controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'). If you do this, the constraints are not taken into consideration. This results in that the generated path from rails (Journey class), will be arbitrary.

If I somewhere in any view use url_for, like

```
url_for(:controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar')
```

rails will choose any arbitrary declared route that matches the controller action, probably the first one declared, skipping to check any advanced constraint.

If the user visits mysite.de/hallo_welt, and the view does something like:

```
= url_for(:controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar', :page => '2')
```

The output might be

```
mysite.de/bonjour_monde?page=2
               ^
          wrong language
```

Actually, I don't use url_for specifically in code, but some gems like kaminari (paginator) do this and that's why you might be limited in using libraries that use the standard helper methods when generating paths.

Now, I'm not so sure if the Journey class should take the request context into consideration. But how would you approach this kind of problem?